Intro.js Highlight an Element in an Iframe
I'm attempting to use the Intro.js library to create tooltips for a number of elements on a web page.  The page includes an iframe, and I want to add a tooltip on a button that is rendered on the page inside that iframe.
Unfortunately, the tooltip will not focus on the button inside the iframe.  The tooltip is shown in the upper left corner of the screen.  I can place a tooltip on the iframe itself but not on any element within that iframe.
I've attempted to set the target of the tooltip by getting the iframe document and using the querySelector function to highlight the button in the iframe.
element: document.querySelector('#iframeContent').contentDocument.querySelector('#startButton')

Does anyone know if its possible to have the Intro.js library focus its tooltip on an element in an iframe?
Please find the complete example on Stackblitz here.

You cant interact with things inside iframes.

@Eloi That is not correct when both pages are hosted on the same domain.  For example, I can use simple Javascript from the parent page to update the value of a textfield in the iframe.

Oh my bad, i just learned a thing today.

Sorry, the fix was proposed but never adopted. Double-checked the code and issue. LINK: https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/480
